# Existence of Tensor Product of Modules

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, tensor-products, tensors, free-modules

I am reading "Commutative Algebra", written by Michael Atiyah. I have a problem about constructing the tensor product of modules. 
In the book, the tensor product of elements of  A-Modules M and N, denoted by $x\otimes y$ for $x \in M$ and $y \in N$, is defined as below:

> Let $C$ denote the free $A$-module  $A^{(M \times N)}$. The elements
>   of $C$ are formal linear combinations of elements of $M\times N$ with
>   coefficients in $A$, i.e. they are expressions of the form
>   $\sum\nolimits_{i=1}^{n}  a_i.(x_i,y_i)(a_i \in A, x_i \in M, y_i \in N).$
>
> Let $D$ be the submodule of $C$ generated by all elements of $C$ of
>   the following types:
>
> $(x+x',y)-(x,y)-(x',y)$
>
> $(x,y+y')-(x,y)-(x,y')$
>
> $(ax,y)-a.(x,y)$
>
> $(x,ay)-a.(x,y)$.
>
> Let $T = C/D$. For each basis element $(x,y)$ of $C$, let $x\otimes y$
>   denote its image in $T$. The mapping $g: M \times N \rightarrow T$,
>   defined by $g(x,y) = x\otimes y$ is $A$-bilinear.

I proved that g is bilinear: $(x+x')\otimes y = (x+x',y) + D.$ From the definition we have $(x+x',y)-(x,y)-(x',y)$ belongs to $D$. Therefore, $(x+x',y) + D = (x,y) + (x',y) + D = (x,y)+D+(x',y)+D = x\otimes y + x'\otimes y. $ 
Likewise, we have $x \otimes (y+y')=x\otimes y + x\otimes y'.$

$(ax)\otimes y = (ax,y)+D = a.(x,y) + D = (x,ay) + D.  \Rightarrow (ax)\otimes y = a.(x\otimes y) = x \otimes (ay).$

My question is that, what is the operation between elements of A and C? What about multiplication between elements of C? Can the above computations be altered in this way: $(x+x',y) = (x,y) + (x',0)$?

Comment: Elements of $C$ could multiply in any number of ways, but that operation is lost in $C/D$ — and anyway you don’t need an internal multiplication for a module. The external multiplication is simply given by the quotient to $C/D$ of the natural external multiplication on $C$ — given the properties of $D$, you can either see $a \cdot (m,n)$ as the image of $a (m,n)$, or that of $(am,n)$, or that of $(m,an)$.

Comment: @Mindlack  is summation of two elements in $C$ component-wise? I have gotten confused about this: $a.(x,y)$, since it's an element of C, isn't it the same as $(ax,ay)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$C$ is a free $A$-module with basis indexed by the set $M\times N$, so the operation between elements of $A$ and $C$ is just the scalar multiplication as $A$-module.

Concretely, if $\sum_i a_i(x_i, y_i)$ is an element of $C$, and $a$ is an element of $A$, then we have $$ a \cdot \sum_i a_i(x_i, y_i) = \sum_i aa_i(x_i, y_i).$$

For your second question, there is no multiplication between elements of $C$ (unless $M$ and $N$ have some extra structure).

For your third question, the notation $(x, y)$ means the basis element index by the element $(x, y) \in M\times N$, hence all the three elements $(x + x', y), (x, y), (x', 0)$ are in general three different basis elements, hence the identity $(x + x', y) = (x, y) + (x', 0)$ is not true in $C$.

Comment: Are three distinct elements of $ M \times N$, three distinct basis elements for $C$?

Comment: Thank you very much, I understood the first two answers but still have confusion about the third one.

Comment: Yes, three distinct elements of $M\times N$ correspond to three distinct basis elements. By definition of basis, there is no $A$-linear relation among them. Although $M \times N$ has an $A$-module structure, in the definition of $C$ we only view it as a set.

Comment: Thank you very much! I understand it now.